# Need help figuring out why this text variable won't set

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can't seem to determine why the text is not being set to the correct reference point. The input text is recording the correct inputs but the text variable never initializes or gets set. Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Assets.Script.PubSubPoc;
using SuperMaxim.Messaging;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class PublisherPubSub: MonoBehaviour
{
    private TMP_InputField InputText;

    private string m_text;

    public string text
    {
        get { return m_text; }
        set
        {
            if (m_text == value || string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_text)) return;
            m_text = value;
            PublishMessage(m_text);
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        InputText = gameObject.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        text = InputText.text;
    }

    private void PublishMessage(string text)
    {
        var payload = new PocPayload
        {
            TextPoc = text
        };
        // publish payload
        Messenger.Default.Publish(payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue looks to be string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_text) this check. I think you wanted to check value instead of m_text in if condition.

ie:

```
if (m_text == value || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return;
```